# I have integer values stored in the array.Sort and display them w.out disarranging the values inside the array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I want to create a program that allows the user to input a number x. The number x will determine the number of integers for user to enter. Allowing the user to enter integers based on the number inputs desired and store them in the array.Also, Display the descending order of the numbers together with the indices without disarranging the values in the original array location.

I already know how to sort them in descending order, but this requires the values to be moved in the array. I do not how to arrange them in descending order retaining their indices from the moment you entered the values stored in array starting the index to 0 until array.length-1.

```
Example:


Enter a number: 4
Enter 4 numbers:
8  
13  
2
15  

Output:     
15 at array[3]
13 at array[1]
8 at array[0]
2 at array[2]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public static void sortArray () {       
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
    int n = in.nextInt();
    int lst[][]  = new int[n][2];
    System.out.println("Enter " + n + " numbers:");
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
        lst[i][0]=in.nextInt();
        lst[i][1]=i;
    }
    for (int i=0;i<n-1;i++)
        for (int j=i+1;j<n;j++)
            if (lst[i][0]<lst[j][0]) {
                int[] tmp = lst[i];
                lst[i]=lst[j];
                lst[j]=tmp;
            }
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
        System.out.println(lst[i][0]+" at array ["+lst[i][1]+"]");
    }                        
}
```

Comment: I have one doubt please reply.while we sorting the array does the value in second dimension also change as we change the value in fist dimesion?

Comment: It is similar but if you look at a 2 dimensional array, the temporary variable must be an array and not a common variable.